# Highcharts line segments and data point?

Tags: highcharts

Trying to plot like [{x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:1},{x:null, y:null}, {x:3,y:1},{x:null, y:null}, {x:5,y:2}]

```
jsfiddle link: [http://jsfiddle.net/rayholland/HSvBj/4/][1]
```

and I want to make data point invisible on line segments but visible on isolated data point.

In another word, I want to draw the following graph but with exactly one series [Link to image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg29267jv0wheqt/one%20series.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

- use two series, but link them (`linkedTo` option) to get just one legend item: http://jsfiddle.net/HSvBj/30/
- use null points, but set `x` value, when `x=null` then where should be that point inserted? I don't know, so for a library it's even harder ;) See: http://jsfiddle.net/HSvBj/31/

Comment: Tried this and it looks decent. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a null x value - the chart can't possibly know what x = null means, or what to do with it.

1) For the points that you want to have null values, you need to provide the appropriate x value

2) For the points that you want to have a marker, you need to signify that in your data array

So, in your plotOptions, disable markers, and in your data array, turn them on point by point:

```
plotOptions : {
  series    : {
    marker: {
      enabled   : false
    }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
series: [{
    data: [
        [0,0],
        [1,1],
        [2,null],
        {x:3,y:1, marker: {enabled: true}},
        [4,null], 
        {x:5,y:2, marker: {enabled: true}}
    ]
}]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/3d3fuhbb/65/